# How format html code in angular schematic?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-schematics

I created a custom schematics, everything is working perfectly, but the html code is not formatted.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="row">
    <% for (let formObject of htmlData)  { %>
        <div class="col-sm-<%= col %>">
        <% if(formObject.type === 'text') { %><dz-input [control]="form.get('<%= formObject.name %>')"></dz-input><% } %>
        <% if(formObject.type === 'select') { %><dz-select [control]="form.get('<%= formObject.name %>')"></dz-select><% } %>
        <% if(formObject.type === 'checkbox') { %><dz-checkbox [control]="form.get('<%= formObject.name %>')"></dz-checkbox><% } %>
        <% if(formObject.type === 'datepicker') { %><dz-datepicker [control]="form.get('<%= formObject.name %>')"></dz-datepicker><% } %>
        <% if(formObject.type === 'multiselect') { %><dz-multiselect [control]="form.get('<%= formObject.name %>')"></dz-multiselect><% } %>
        </div>
    <% } %>
    </div>
</form>
```

Generated HTML:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="row">
    
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <dz-input [control]="form.get('texto')"></dz-input>
        
        
        
        
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <dz-input [control]="form.get('texto2')"></dz-input>
        
        
        
        
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        
        <dz-select [control]="form.get('teste_1')"></dz-select>
        
        
        
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        
        <dz-select [control]="form.get('teste2')"></dz-select>
        
        
        
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        
        
        <dz-checkbox [control]="form.get('oooo')"></dz-checkbox>
        
        
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        
        
        
        
        
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        
        
        
        <dz-datepicker [control]="form.get('teste')"></dz-datepicker>
        
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        
        
        
        
        <dz-multiselect [control]="form.get('aaaa')"></dz-multiselect>
        </div>
    
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I remove those white spaces?  I've tried to modify the file entry content at index.html but I got error:

> Cannot set property content of `#<LazyFileEntry>` which has only a
> getter

Which is the best way to do it?